# Installing source package has no effect

Tags: cygwin

I am trying to install libgmp sources as I am trying to build some other source that requires `gmp.h`.

In Cygwin `setup-x86_64.exe` I Search for `gmp` and it finds the `libgmp` line which says "6.1.2-1  Keep" on the left, "n/a" under "Bin?" , and empty checkbox under "Src?".

I check the checkbox and proceed and it appears to install something and succeed. However, `gmp.h` doesn't appear anywhere under /usr/include (or anywhere else that I can find); and when I run `setup-x86_64.exe` again, the Src box is unchecked.

What's going wrong? I have tried with a few other libraries too, in all cases the source doesn't seem to appear and the Src checkbox resets next time the setup is run.

Comment: Are you sure you need the source package? Could be that you need 'the development package libgmp-devel instead.

Comment: @pak you're right, that was what I needed

Answer (score 3):

The development packages include the header files needed when building other software, rather than the source packages. In this case, the `libgmp-devel` package is what's required.